# Cannot find dll or dependency

Tags: c#, vba, dll

I'm trying to write a C# dll for use in an Access VBA application. The dll works fine (only) when called with full file path:

```
Declare Function MyObject Lib "\path\to\my.dll" () As Object
```

despite the .dll being in the same folder.

The problem arises however when I call another dll (Test.dll) from my.dll (also in the same folder). I get:

[image: error screenshot]

I've tried adding the path to Environment Variables Path (which allowed me to declare my.dll function without full path) but that didn't work... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How long is the pathname?   There is a limit to the number of characters that excel will recognize.

Comment: 108 chars long. Maybe that's the problem but it was picking up the initial dll with the full path without issue, and adding the path to the env vars should eliminate that problem I would have thought.

Comment: You are right at the limit.  Adding the environmental path may add a few characters.  I've seen case where the number of characters where is starts failing varies by a couple of characters.  Never figure out why it isn't always the exact same number.

Answer (score 0):

Run depends.exe on the dll. If a dependency is missing vba claims it can't find the dll. Go figure.